# Getting table id with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my jquery code. I have some tables on a page and am trying to show the table id in an alert. For reason the alert says the variable is undefined. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
[See my demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/8wfn2pk9/41/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.myForm').submit(function(e) {
 var data = $(this).find('table').attr('id')
                alert (data);
   e.preventDefault();

        });

    });
```

The Tables

```
<table id="mytable1">
<tr>
<td class="tags">
 <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">Julian</span>
<td class="tags">
    <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">Paul</span>
</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2">
<button type="submit" name="submit3">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> ADD
</button>
</form>
</tr>
</table>


<table id="mytable2">
<tr>
<td class="tags">
 <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">John</span>
<td class="tags">
    <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">Ben</span>
</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2">
<button type="submit" name="submit3">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> ADD
</button>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is not in the form it's present in its ancestor level. Use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** method to get the table present in the ancestor level.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myForm').submit(function(e) {
    var data = $(this).closest('table').attr('id')
    alert(data);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myForm').submit(function(e) {
    var data = $(this).closest('table').attr('id')
    alert(data);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable1">
  <tr>
    <td class="tags">
      <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">Julian</span>
      <td class="tags">
        <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">Paul</span>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2">
      <button type="submit" name="submit3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> ADD
      </button>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>


<table id="mytable2">
  <tr>
    <td class="tags">
      <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">John</span>
      <td class="tags">
        <span class="label label-danger" id="tag">Ben</span>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2">
      <button type="submit" name="submit3">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> ADD
      </button>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form you don't have any table, but to get the closest or whatever, another approach, is to add an attr in the form with the id:

```
<form id="myForm" class="myForm" action="" data-table="mytable1" method="post">
```

And get the attribute in jquery:

```
 var data = $(this).attr('data-table')
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/qs5zd9uf/